# Improve performance using IsNumeric function in loop which is exeecute 1 to 1 caror or more in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, isnumeric

I have one function which is written in VB.net, Code is look like below.

```
For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To nRows - 1
        Dim max As Integer = -1
        Dim arrTemp() As String
        arrTemp = Nothing

        For columnIndex As Integer = 0 To nCols - 1
            If IsNumeric(arrTranspose(rowIndex, columnIndex)) Then
                Dim iVal As Integer = arrTranspose(rowIndex, columnIndex)

                If iVal < 0 Then
                    iVal = Math.Abs(iVal)
                End If

                If max < iVal Then
                    max = iVal
                    ReDim Preserve arrTemp(max)
                End If
                arrTemp(iVal) += String.Format("{0},", (columnIndex + 1))
            End If
        Next
        arrRespondentIDs(rowIndex) = arrTemp
    Next
```

nRow = 210
nCols = 64772

In above code first loop execution take 4 to 5 minutes, I have research and observed then Due to IsNumeric function it's take more time, Not sure about this.

Can any one have Idea which part of code is causing performance issue. Please share your idea.

Thanks,
Mohmedsadiq.

Comment: Can you show how `arrTranspose` is defined?  How big is it and how long are the strings it contains?  Or does it even contain strings, for that matter?  How certain are you that `IsNumeric` is the problem?  For instance, ReDim Preserve could be very expensive on a large array.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, arrTranspose is two dimension array define as a Dim arrTranspose(nRows, nCols) As String ...  It has value like 0 to 99 or . , ; , "" , : , ' , etc due to this reason I have to check value is numeric or not.

Comment: if the first element of a column is numeric, then all elements of this column will be numeric right ? and if first element is not, then all elements are not ? If so, just check the first row to build a list of numeric column. Depending on the numeric/non numeric ratio, you might gain quite some time, since you don't have to check any more after. But if your source is a DataBase you can know if a column is numeric ... by looking at its schema.

Answer (score 2):

You've written code with O(n^2) complexity, that doesn't scale well.  Not much you can do about that from the looks of it.  Specific ways to improve the code inside the inner loop:

- You use IsNumeric() which is a very expensive function since it deals with a lot of corner cases.  Like values that express a monetary amount and *may* include things like parentheses for negative amounts or a unit like $ or "USD".  But you are actually only interested in values that can be converted to an **Integer**, the next thing you do, the IsNumeric() function doesn't tell you that.  Certainly such a monetary amount will not convert well.  So use a more accurate conversion function, one that's also quicker, like Integer.TryParse().
- The `If iVal < 0 Then` test is pointless, the Math.Abs() function already does that.  Just call it directly.
- ReDim Preserve arrTemp(max) is horribly expensive, very surprising that it didn't pop out in your profile session.  You will reallocate and copy the array over and over again.  You really should use List(Of String) instead of an array.  It is in particular good at minimizing this kind of expense.
- The `arrTemp(iVal) += String.Format("{0},", (columnIndex + 1))` statement is expensive and commits the same kind of sin that got you into this trouble in the first place.  It is very unwise to store data as strings, it is a very clumsy data format that forever needs to be converted back, burning cpu cycles for no benefit.  You only care about strings when a human looks at data, that only happens at distinct places in your code.  A program operates most efficiently if the data is kept in binary format.  There's no ambiguity here, the columnIndex is always an Integer.  Combined with the previous bullet, the arrTemp should not be an array of strings but a List(Of Integer).

Find additional ways to improve this code by getting rid of String as a data type in the rest of your code.  Even Object is better than String.

Comment: it's not O(n^2), it is O(m*n) where n is number of rows and n number of columns. Otherwise you are right : the code shown above is pure crap.